# Android Service Framework

Tags: android, android-service

I have two queries regarding the Service framework provided by Android

1. I read from Android documentation the following

   > Clients can also use Context.bindService() to obtain a persistent connection to a service. This likewise creates the service if it is not already running (calling onCreate() while doing so), but does not call onStartCommand(). The client will receive the IBinder object that the service returns from its onBind(Intent) method, allowing the client to then make calls back to the service. The service will remain running as long as the connection is established (whether or not the client retains a reference on the service's IBinder).

   Does this mean, that i will need to manually call OnStartCommand on the service?
   Please if my understanding is correct.
2. Is it allowed to or the return values from onStartCommand
   For e.g., can i return something like this

   ```
   return START_FLAG_REDELIVERY | START_FLAG_RETRY
   ```

   I am not sure if this makes sense anyway.

Answer (score 1):

1. You can first call `startService` to make sure the service is running and then bind to it.
2. The return value of onStartCommand should be one of the following:
   START_STICKY, START_NOT_STICKY, START_REDELIVER_INTENT, or START_STICKY_COMPATIBILITY.

Read about them here:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#START_NOT_STICKY